# Importing DAT file that contains double quotes within few fields

Tags: sql-server, import, ssis

I'm using SQL Server 2014 Management Studio - Import and Export wizard to import a `.DAT` file into a SQL Server table.

However, while all of these records are text qualified with `"` double quotes, some of the field values have double quotes within them. SQL Server aborts the package every time it hits a row like that. Any solution?

```
"Field A"|"Field B"|"Field C"

"Value A"|"Another value "with" for B"|"Value C"
```

Comment: Are there pipes within the fields? Seems like you could just NOT say the fields are surrounded by quotes, then just split on pipes. Sure, you'll end up parsing the wrapping quotes into your table, but you can replace those after the fact.

Comment: @Xedni that just worked! you're a genious. However, now I'm stuck with a bunch of fields enclosed in double-quotes. Any way out of that one? :)

Comment: Through the import export wizard, probably not. If you use full-blown SSIS you could create a derived column to chomp off the leading and trailing quotes using an expression. Alternatively once the data is in SQL, you could do something akin to `substring(myField, 2, len(myField) - 2)` (either through an update, or when you move the data to another, cleaned up, presentation table)